# Unreal Engine 4 ray tracing doesn't seem to ignore actor when called through blueprints

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So I've been making a game in Unreal Engine 4 and I've been trying to use a combination of C++ and Blueprints. It's been going fairly smoothly, but I was doing some refactoring and decided to move a function in my gun class into the blueprint instead. The function as seen below takes a reference to the player which it passes into the ShootRay function so that it knows which Actor to ignore with the raycast.

[image]

[image]

For some reason when I tried to convert the FireGun function into a Blueprint as seen below, the ray hits the player despite me still passing the player in as the Actor to ignore.

[image]

I don't understand why this would work in C++ but not in blueprints, but I'm guessing it has something to do with calling blueprint functions from C++ which then call other C++ functions causing something weird to happen. I would really like to have this code in the blueprint to keep it easy to extend later on. Does anyone know what's going on?

Note: I know in the image of the blueprint it says custom event, but that's just because I took the screenshot after reverting it back to C++ and removing the BlueprintImplementable tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out for some reason the length variable in the ShootRay function was overflowing in the Blueprint but not in the C++ code. Removing a few zeros fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0):

(Can't comment on your answer, so will write it like this)

Yeah, that's a huge number (just removing 1 zero is enough to work I guess). Maybe in C++ it won't overflow because the hit happens before it reaches max 32bit value? Does line trace ever end if you shoot in the air because of the overflow (when you only done it in C++)? This made me curious, will test it out just for fun!

I think that because blueprints operate a bit differently, trough scripts, it will check the value of your float before the operation begins, but I might be completely wrong. Still very new to programming.

Glad you found your problem! Best of luck!